# redirecting technical links to SEO links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I have a map file which is working fine with SEO-friendly URLs

Now the customer want that the user should not be allowed to access the technical links means only SEO links should be accessable

e.g my map file looks like

```
buche-massiv-weiss-lackiert.html /?page=datail&productid=1212
```

at the moment SEO is working, but what I need is that If the user calls this 
technical link i.e

`/?page=datail&productid=1212`

if should also be first redirected to SEO link and then the page should be called.

what will be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same mapping file add a reverse entries like this:

```
/?page=datail&productid=1212 buche-massiv-weiss-lackiert.html
```

Then have this rule at top of your htaccess for redirection to pretty URL:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/*(/.*?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteCond %1::${mymap:%1} ^(.*)::.
RewriteRule .* ${mymap:%1}? [L,NE,R=301]
```

This is assuming name of your `RewriteMap` is `mymap`. Change it to whatever your map name is.

Answer (score 0):

With Helicon Ape you could use reverse map on the same map file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap map_rev txt_rev:my_map_file.txt [NC]
RewriteCond ${map_rev:$1|NOT_FOUND} (.*)
RewriteCond %1 !NOT_FOUND 
RewriteRule (.+) %1 [R]
```

Then your existing map rule. 
With ISAPI_Rewrite you will have to create another reversed map file and make sure contents of both files are synched. Usage is something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap map_rev txt:my_rev_map_file.txt [NC]
RewriteCond ${map_rev:$1|NOT_FOUND} (.*)
RewriteCond %1 !NOT_FOUND 
RewriteRule (.+) %1 [R]
```